# Google caching subdomain as root domain

Tags: seo, google-search

Recently I've been working on regional targeting for my client and I've noticed that the Australian Google view uses the American website instead of Australian website and caches it. It copies the American description & title rather than using the Australian site's one.

Here are the regional targeting meta tags for the site:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://au.example.com" hreflang="en-au" type="text/html" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com" hreflang="en-us" type="text/html"/>
```

I've used the Moz forums and no-one was able to identify the problem, and I'm hoping someone here would be able to assist me.

Also note, that through accessing the Australian website normally, it does not use US site data. I also re-cached  the website recently so it wouldn't be 'old'.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Do the inner pages of your website belong to the language versions too? If yes, you should implement the tag on every of those pages, not only the homepage.

Comment: Okay fair enough, Thanks for the heads up. but would this resolve the issue?

Comment: Also just notice, that your link brings to "This is Google's cache of http://www.clubmatestravel.com/." So, this is the cache of American version and all is ok.

Comment: This is straight from Australian search results through? And the domain in the URL is au.site.com

Comment: Yes, it looks like the next - http://joxi.ru/J2b9XZ1SWoXxm6

Comment: Yeah, no idea whats going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23487/discussion-between-marian-and-oliver-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the US version as both the canonical and alternate version:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/about"/>
<link rel='alternate' hreflang='en-us' href='http://au.example.com/about' />
<link rel='alternate' hreflang='en-au' href='http://example.com/about' />
```

Fix these tags and also check out this resource on locale-aware crawling by Googlebot: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6144055?hl=en

Comment: Wow, that took me forever to find. I love you man!

Comment: It means, canonical have higher priority for Google than alternative, right?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say "priority" but rather default vs. alternate or variation. Desktop will always be default and on top of that, whichever locale and language you choose to be your website's primarily locale and language will also be default. 

So, your website can be in Spanish from a .mx TLD but also have locale and language variations for English and other languages. Without explicitly specifying which is the default version, Google might think this content is duplicate amongst other things. This is also a good way to discover content bots might not have found otherwise.